# Where do i 'setcookie' to record http_referer in Drupal 6?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, cookies, http-referer

I've got my php working to set a cookie storing the http_referer the visitor came from,
but how(or where) do i put this code in my Drupal theme/installation, to make it set cookie when a visitor first lands on my Drupal site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a custom module using function hook_init()